# Angular2 component method returns NaN despite type casting

Tags: methods, angular, numbers, nan

This has slowed me down today....

I have the following method inside a component:

```
utility(prop:string):number {
 let ob:number;
 this.meals.map( something => {
  something.items.map( item => {
   ob += item.info[prop];
   console.log(prop, item.info[prop]);
  });
 });    
 return ob;
}
```

These are some of the ways I call this function:

```
 fatStats(){
  let total_fat: number = 0;
  let total_sat_fat: number = 0;

  return {
   totalFat: total_fat = this.utility('fat'),
   totalFatDV: ( total_fat / allowedFat ) * 100,
   totalSatFat: total_sat_fat = this.utility('satfat'),
   totalSatFatDV: ( total_sat_fat / allowedSatFat ) * 100,
   totalPolyFat: this.utility('polyfat'),
   totalMonoFat: this.utility('monofat'),
   totalTransFat: this.utility('transfat')
  }
 }
```

The fatStats method is called from my view template:

```
<div class="label head">Total Fat
 <div id="totalFat" 
      class="weight total_fat_na">
      {{ fatStats().totalFat | number : "1.0-1"}}g
 </div>
</div>
<div id="totalFatP" 
     class="dv total_fat_na_p">
     {{ fatStats().totalFatDV | number : ".0-0" }}%
</div> 
<div class="labellight">Saturated Fat
 <div id="totalSatFat" 
      class="weight saturated_fat_na">
      {{ fatStats().totalSatFat | number : ".0-0" }}g
 </div> 
</div>
<div id="totalSatFat" 
     class="dv saturated_fat_na">
     {{ fatStats().totalSatFatDV | number : ".0-0" }}%
</div>
```

The console.log indicates correct properties and values, but in all cases the actual output is a NaN, despite various attempts to force a number out of this utility function I can't get it to.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Steve

Comment: A plunker would probably be helpful to investigate.

Comment: You're right, but that will take time - maybe tomorrow

Comment: Your source object would help. For performance, you should also store the results in a variable and map to that from your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this took awhile, but sometimes you just have to go back to less sexy code..

I replaced the internals of the utility function and now it does exactly what I want when the view changes.

```
utility(obj, prop:string){
 let ob:number = 0;
 obj.forEach(function(my){
   my.items.forEach(function(item){
   ob += item.info[prop] * ( item.portion / 100 );
  });
 });
 return ob;
}
```

This returns a number for any and all requests. No more annoying NaN's.

Peace

Steve